# Mean of all vector values with unique names

Tags: r

I have a large list of non-unique named values, i.e.:

```
tscores
        11461         11461         11461         11461         14433
-1.966196e+01  7.808853e-01  2.065178e+01  5.630565e+00 -7.295436e+00
        14433         14433         14433         14433         14433
 2.036339e+00 -6.704906e+00  1.603803e+00 -1.118324e+01  1.450554e+00
        14102         16153         16189         18563         18563
-1.137429e+01  7.053336e-02  1.011208e+00 -7.811194e+00 -6.749376e-01
        18563         18563         22042         22042         22042
 7.480217e-01 -9.909211e-01 -9.577424e-01 -7.887699e-02 -4.867706e-01
```

I'd like to be able to pull out a subvector of all values that correspond to a name more efficiently.  At the moment, I'm using:

```
u_tscores <- sapply(unique(names(tscores)), function(name, scores) {mean(scores[names(scores)==name])}, scores=tscores)
```

Which is far too slow for what I need.  I know there has to be an easier way to get all values with the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best bet you have is using `lapply` on the list obtained by `split(tscores,names(tscores))`. Wins you about a fivefold in speed :

```
n <- 1000000
tscores <- runif(n)
names(tscores) <- sample(letters,n,replace=T)

system.time(
   X <- tapply(tscores, names(tscores), mean)
)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.89    0.00    0.89 

 system.time(
   X2 <- sapply(unique(names(tscores)), function(name, scores){   
            mean(scores[names(scores)==name])}, scores=tscores)
)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.73    0.05    0.78 

system.time(
  X3 <- unlist(lapply(split(tscores,names(tscores)),mean))
)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.11    0.02    0.13
```

EDIT :

```
system.time(X3 <- sapply(split(tscores,names(tscores)),mean))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.00    0.14
```

Comment: Thanks!  So split actually does the grouping?  That is useful!

Comment: @Vincent: instead of looping over the names, you loop over a list that is split according to the names. That requires less calculations, as you don't have to go over the complete vector tscores in every loop cycle. In general, `tapply` and `apply` rely on `lapply/sapply` internally, but have more overhead for preparing the data. As I showed in my edit, `sapply` is actually a wrapper for `lapply`. `sapply` with USE.NAMES=FALSE and simplify=FALSE is exactly the same as `lapply`. Generally speaking, if you can use lists, you'll be faster than when you rely on other solutions.

Comment: @Edd : `split` returns a list of vectors split according to the second argument. As you get a list, you can use the full power of the apply family. see also `?split`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Joris! Makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
tapply(tscores, names(tscores), mean)
```

I'm note sure if this is more efficient, but probably not less efficient...

Answer (score 1):

Hey there, 
it seems you will be subsetting this multiple times (that is, you won't be selecting from many elements of this type just once each).  Your data formatting doesn't quite seem geared towards this purpose.  So list the values by name

```
tvalues <- sapply(unique(names(tscores)), function(x, tscores) as.numeric(tscores[names(tscores) == x])), tscores=tscores)
```

That should give you a list of unique-tscore-name-named tscore value numeric vectors.  Then, just `tvalues$name` whenever you need to select a name's values.  That should knock an order or so off your complexity.  Apologies for errors and false assumptions.